# Get form field format itext7

Tags: itext7

I am getting form fields from the PDF document but I did not see any method for getting form field format ForExample there are multiple text form fields in my document including Number field, Date field, Percentage field.
Is there any way to get field format type in itext7

Comment: What do you mean by format? do you mean the format in which the value of the field has been written? Then isn't it possible for you to get the value and to inspect it manually?

Comment: There is an option to set text field format as Date, Number, Percentage etc in Adobe writter. I want to get that field format in itext7.
ForExample:
If field format is set to number then the end application will only allow number characters in the field.

Comment: Those format options are not immediate pdf form field properties, they merely are enforced by javascript event listeners (on pdf viewers with javascript capabilities which are not by configuration disabled). Thus, to determine whether a field had a specific format option set, you have to analyze the javascript associated with it.

Comment: @mkl. Alright but I did not see any method regarding Getting javascript method in PDFAcroForm whereas till ItextSharp5 this method was available

Answer (score 1):

@Uladzimir Asipchuk
/TU dictionary contains ToolTip value. Format value is contained in /AA >> /K dictionary in PDF structure. However I have extracted the JS Method after some tries and exploring the PDF structure through Pre-Flight. The following code snippet give the associated JSMethod if any:

```
    PdfDictionary additionalActions = formField.GetAdditionalAction();
    if (additionalActions != null)
    {
        PdfDictionary formatDictionary = additionalActions.GetAsDictionary(PdfName.K);
        PdfString jsMethod = formatDictionary.GetAsString(PdfName.JS);
        string fieldJsMethod = jsMethod.GetValue();
    }
```

Comment: Actually Adobe sets a descriptive /TU along with /K entry of /AA dictionary, so it's possible to check the "format" of Adobe created field in two ways.

Answer (score 0):

I created a pdf via Adobe (as you suggested) and I indeed was able to set the "format" of a text field as `Date`, `Number`, `Percentage`, `Email`,..

Then I opened the resultant pdf in RUPS (an utility program used to open the pdf's tree) and investigated it.
It turned out that Adobe sets the "format" which you want to get as a `/TU` value of the field's dictionary. For example, for `Percentage` it's `percentfield` and for `Email` - `emailfield`.

Now the only thing you need to find the "format" of your fieeld is to get the value of `/TU` entry of your field:

```
field.getValue().getPdfObject().get(PdfName.TU)
```